# Redis Unresolve dependency issue with Play

Tags: playframework, redis, sbt

I am pretty new to Play and Redis and need some basic help.  I downloaded the redis plugin from https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis  .  I thought it would be best to run the sample app first before writing my own app.  When I tried to run the sample app, I got:

```
mbp-2493:sample john$ play --verbose run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/john/Personal/ML/cloudbee/play-plugins-master/redis/sample/project
[info] Set current project to j (in build file:/Users/john/Personal/ML/cloudbee/play-plugins-master/redis/sample/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/john/Personal/ML/cloudbee/play-plugins-master/redis/sample/}j...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.10;2.2.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.10;2.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/john/Personal/ML/cloudbee/play-2.2.0/repository/local/com.typesafe/play-plugins-redis_2.10/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/Users/john/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/play-plugins-redis_2.10/2.2.0/play-plugins-redis_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-oss-snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/typesafe/play-plugins-redis_2.10/2.2.0/play-plugins-redis_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play-plugins-redis_2.10/2.2.0/play-plugins-redis_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play-plugins-redis_2.10/2.2.0/play-plugins-redis_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.10;2.2.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Oct 28, 2013 5:26:51 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

Try that in project/Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "j"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
       "com.typesafe" % "play-plugins-redis_2.10" % "2.1.1",//not the recent version, but this one is published
       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" % "2.2.0"
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe",
      resolvers += "pk11 repo" at "http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk"
    )
}
```

Or leave the build files untouched and publish it locally:

```
git clone https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins && \
cd play-plugins/redis && \
sbt publish-local
```

Helpful sources:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/4gJcGfRjqVE
- https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/issues/93
- https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/blob/redis-2.1.1/redis/project/Build.scala#L11

Comment: I'd change the answer a bit to become `resolvers ++= Seq(...)` and use `%%` for the `libraryDependencies` (and then remove `2.10`). WDYT?

Comment: The current code is tested and it worked. The questioner is is free to use your style.

Comment: It doesn't solve the error after I tried adding the above to plugins.sbt.  There is no build.sbt file in the sample code.

Comment: I updated my answer for Build.scala and added another approach to put it in your local ivy folder.